# How to use update Method of Message Digest Class

Tags: java, md5, chunking, message-digest, text-chunking

I'm working on a data encryption project and just wanted to ask how to use the method **update** of message digest class. 
In a code snippet of MD5 implementation, this was written.

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.*;

class MD5{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner cin=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s=cin.nextLine();
        try{
            MessageDigest md=MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            byte[] dataBytes=s.getBytes(); 
            md.update(dataBytes,0,0);
            byte[] digest=md.digest();
            for(byte b:digest)System.out.printf("%02x",b);
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

and i'm confused about this line

```
md.update(dataBytes,0,0);
```

what are the three arguments are used for? And how to hash only a certain number say 192 bytes of a data.

Comment: check the docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#update(byte[],%20int,%20int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what i get from [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html), and [this](http://book2s.com/java/api/java/security/messagedigest/update-3.html)

> what are the three arguments are used for?

```
update(byte[] input, int offset, int len)
```

Updates the digest using the specified array of bytes, starting at the specified offset.

`input` is the array which is supposed to be hashed

`offset` is the index of the array which is the starting point

`len` specifies how far from the starting index should it go